# How do I use $unwind and then $group in the same mongodb query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following mongodb structure...

```json
[
    {
        track: 'Newcastle',
        time: '17:30',
        date: '22/04/2022',
        bookmakers: [
            {
                bookmaker: 'Coral',
                runners: [
                    {
                        runner: 'John',
                        running: true,
                        odds: 3.2
                    },
                    ...
                ]
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

I'm trying to find filter the bookmakers array for each document to only include the objects that match the specified bookmaker values, for example:

```json
{ 'bookmakers.bookmaker': { $in: ['Coral', 'Bet365'] } }
```

At the moment, I'm using the following mongodb query to only select the bookmakers that are specified, however I need to put the documents back together after they've been seperated by the '$unwind', is there a way I can do this using $group?

```json
await HorseRacingOdds.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$bookmakers" },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            bookmakers: "$bookmakers"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "_id": 0,
            "__v": 0,
            "lastUpdate": 0
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Not related to your question but you should **never** store date/time values as string, it's a design flaw. Store always proper `Date` objects.

Comment: Why would it be a design flaw?

Comment: You will face problems with formatting, comparison (later or earlier than), etc. Here on SO you can find hundreds or even thousands of questions because date/time values have been stored as strings rather than proper `DATE` data type. It is not specific to MongoDB, it applies to any database system. For example `db.collection.find({date: {$gt: '31/01/2000'}})` will not return your sample record.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the advice, I'll change it to date format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a plain `$addFields` with `$filter`?

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "bookmakers": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$bookmakers",
          "as": "b",
          "cond": {
            "$in": [
              "$$b.bookmaker",
              [
                "Coral",
                "Bet365"
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "_id": 0,
      "__v": 0,
      "lastUpdate": 0
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FYLZ2B9y62H) for your reference.